# wp7 - Recover files deleted by Isolated Storage Tool

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

Ok I had a load of data I saved in my app and downloaded it via Isolated Storage Tool. Then I updated my app and went to upload the saved data back to the phone when I accidentally hit the download button which wiped the saved data :-(

So I thought ok I will just run some software to recover deleted files on my PC as it's just happened... nope they files are not found. (Note I installed the software to a different drive so it wouldn't overwrite the deleted files)

Are those files on my pc really gone? i.e did the download from Isolated Storage Tool actually permanently deleted the files I had?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to recover the files, if you don't have them stored in the `IsoStore` in the application itself or somewhere locally.

Comment: I managed to recover them using a deep scan in the recovery tool I was using. When a file is deleted on the pc, so long as it has not been over written, most recovery tools can get it back with ease. For some reason the Isolated Storage Tool wiped the files and overwrite them even if there is nothing in the IsoStore for the app on the phone.